# How can I NOT show the Request new password tab within the /user (login) page for one particular user

Tags: users

Drupal 7 /user url goes to a page that has 2 tabs Login and Request new password which is what I want for all of our users except for one.  How can I NOT show the Request new password tab within the /user (login) page for one particular user ($user->name)?

Comment: Do you need to hide it or just disable it for that user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just wish to hide the tab, you can do that by using the [Tab Tamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module. However, the user would still be able to access the form through the URL `http://<yoursite>/user/password`.

If you wish to disable (along with hiding) the password tab, you can implement the [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7).

```
function MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  //condition to check the user
  global $user;
  if($user->id == '<USER_ID_OF_THE_USER>') { //can use $user->name as well
    $items['user/password']['access callback'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this looking for solutions to the same problem. However, this code will not work because hook_menu_alter and hook_menu only run when the menu's are rebuilt. So, the if clause will only execute when the user, most likely admin, does a cache clear, not when the targeted user is using the site.

My solution:

```
function MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/password']['access callback'] = 'MODULE_user_access_callback';
  $items['user/%user/edit']['access callback'] = 'MODULE_user_access_callback';
}
function MODULE_user_access_callback() {
  global $user;
  // target "guest" account or "anonymous"
  if ($user->name == 'guest' || $user->uid == 0) {
    return FALSE;
  } else {
    return TRUE;
}
```